# SAPUI5: can not access `sortItemData` in the sap.m.P13nSortPanel at update event.

Tags: sapui5

I want to collect `sortItemData` in `sap.m.P13nSortPanel` object on update time.

So I wrote the following function:

```
_onUpdateSortItem: function(oEvent) {
        var parameters = oEvent.getParameters();
        var oSortItemData = oEvent.getParameter("sortItemData");
        if (oSortItemData) {
            this._oSorter[parameters.key] = {
                sColumnKey: oSortItemData.getColumnKey(),
                sOperation: oSortItemData.getOperation()
            };
        }
    },
```

And bound it as the `onUpdate` handler. The problem is that the  `oSortItemData` is undefined while if I use this function for `onAddSortItem` event then it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the code of [sap.m.P13nSortPanel](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/95c1676f6867808653a2d71cc2929f3fd02c4243/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/P13nSortPanel.js#L403) that fires the event, I assume that you did not bind the `sortItems` aggregation. Please have a look at the Explored [example](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.P13nDialog/preview) as well. There you can see that the panel uses two aggregations, `items` and `sortItems`.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have to bind it to the SortPanel inside of the onAddEvent